# AOSP repo sync - shutil Error [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: android-source

I decided to start the creation of a custom ROM from the android source code.

I followed the steps at [the docs](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading):

1. [Installed](https://source.android.com/setup/develop?#installing-repo) the Repo launcher
2. [Initialized](https://source.android.com/setup/develop?#installing-repo) the AOSP repo

> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

> Your identity is: personal-info myCoolEmail@somewhere.com...

> repo has been initialized in /mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source

This successfully creates the `.repo` directory, but the issue comes right when executing `repo sync`:

```
Fetching:  0% (0/1075) warming uperror: Cannot fetch platform/art (Error: [(<DirEntry 'heads'>, '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/art.git/refs/heads', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/art.git/refs/heads'"), (<DirEntry 'tags'>, '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/art.git/refs/tags', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/art.git/refs/tags'"), ('/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/project-objects/platform/art.git/refs', '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/art.git/refs', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/art.git/refs'")])
error: Cannot fetch platform/build/bazel (Error: [(<DirEntry 'heads'>, '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/bazel.git/refs/heads', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/bazel.git/refs/heads'"), (<DirEntry 'tags'>, '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/bazel.git/refs/tags', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/bazel.git/refs/tags'"), ('/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/project-objects/platform/build/bazel.git/refs', '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/bazel.git/refs', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/bazel.git/refs'")])
error: Cannot fetch platform/build/pesto (Error: [(<DirEntry 'heads'>, '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/pesto.git/refs/heads', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/pesto.git/refs/heads'"), (<DirEntry 'tags'>, '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/pesto.git/refs/tags', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/pesto.git/refs/tags'"), ('/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/project-objects/platform/build/pesto.git/refs', '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/pesto.git/refs', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/projects/build/pesto.git/refs'")])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/main.py", line 651, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/main.py", line 627, in _Main
    result = run()
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/main.py", line 620, in <lambda>
    run = lambda: repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/main.py", line 286, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 1027, in Execute
    all_projects = self._FetchMain(opt, args, all_projects, err_event,
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 499, in _FetchMain
    success, fetched = self._Fetch(to_fetch, opt, err_event, ssh_proxy)
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 457, in _Fetch
    if not _ProcessResults(results):
  File "/mnt/e/MyCustomROM/source/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 410, in _ProcessResults
    for results in results_sets:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 448, in <genexpr>
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 868, in next
    raise value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x7f1f1ab32f10>'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'posix.DirEntry' object")'
```

For more (hopefully) useful info:

- I'm running `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` as a *Windows subsystem* (that's the
  reason the path where I located the project is in `/mnt/e/...`)
- Also using `Python 3.8.10` (and of course did this: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is behavior the same when you init and sync AOSP project somewhere in home folder (e.g. ~/MyCustomROM/source)?

Comment: Seems not to be, I'm currently testing it (`/home/myUser`)to see if any other issues arise. Thanks for your point! If the issue is related to the `/mnt/e` drive, any idea on why it isn't working even with `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue, and I fixed it by change the folder security of Windows.
Give the folder full control permissions to group Users or your own user

See this picture:
[Folder Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP6hK.png)